# Sorting a NSMutableArray

Tags: ios, objective-c, sorting, nsarray

I am currently parsing my `NSArray` through this code

```
NSSortDescriptor *sort = [NSSortDescriptor sortDescriptorWithKey:@"title" ascending:YES];
[myArray sortUsingDescriptors:[NSArray arrayWithObject:sort]];
```

And myArray objects is Ep 1 to Ep 50, unsorted. The problem is in the number with a single digit value. And I cannot add a 0 prefix to it cause the array is dynamic and some object might cause crash.

I am expecting this:

> Ep 1 Ep 2 Ep 3..... Ep 10 Ep 11 Ep 12 Ep 13.... Ep 20 Ep 21...

But my output is this

> Ep 1 Ep 10 Ep 11 Ep 12 Ep 13..... Ep 2 Ep20 Ep 21 Ep 22.... Ep 3 Ep 30 Ep 31......

Now, How can I sort it properly?

Answer (score 3):

You need to use `NSNumericSearch` option with `sortedArrayUsingComparator` like this.

If your array contains custom object.

```
NSArray *sortedArray = [myArray sortedArrayUsingComparator:^(Episode *ep1, Episode *ep2) {
     return [ep1.title compare:ep2.title options:NSNumericSearch];
}];
```

If your array contains `NSDictionary`.

```
NSArray *sortedArray = [myArray sortedArrayUsingComparator:^(NSDictionary *dic1, NSDictionary *dic2) {
     return [(NSString*)[dic1 objectForKey:@"title"] compare:(NSString*)[dic2 objectForKey:@"title"] options:NSNumericSearch];
}];
```

Comment: Small mistake: `obj1.title` => `ep1.title`.

Comment: @Larme  Typo mistake, Thanks for correcting me :)